# How to find in mysql_fetch_array while and foreach cycle variables?

Tags: php

I need to do a search in each $row2 variable, so i could find if there is columns that are not equal to $row1 column.

This is what I tried,

```
$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT gpu FROM ng2s3_content');
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT gpu FROM bigc3_gpu");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
foreach ($row2 as $ar) {
if ($ar == $row1[0]) {      
            }
            else {
                echo $ar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off doing such acrobatics in MySQL

Comment: And your strategy won't work: you cannot call `mysql_fetch_array($result2)` simply again and again and expect to re-read the query results of the second query again and again whilst iterating over the rows of the first query. It really would make more sense to do this on sql level inside the database. If not: first read the rows into arrays, then iterate over those array using your while loops.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want distinct values from your database ,
use mysql query , that will return a resource with distinct values ,

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT gpu FROM ng2s3_content UNION SELECT gpu FROM bigc3_gpu');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['gpu'];
}
```